# how can i make message appear as an envelope in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I drag a message from the toolbox to my diagram1 of Enterprise Architect v15.2.1560.
it appears as an envelope of type Message.
it also nicely appears in the project browser.

I drag that message from the project browser to my diagram2.
it appears as an object (blue rectangle).
how can i make it appear as an envelope?

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on whether you drag it as a **Link** or as an **Instance** in this dialog.

[image]

- Instance
  Creates a new object, classified with the original element.
- Link
  Simply puts this element on the diagram

The blue object is probably an instance of the message. (which isn't valid BPMN, but that's another issue)

You can use **Ctrl+Drag** to make sure this dialog pops up when dragging an element to a diagram.

Comment: dankjewel, Geert